# Convert Standard Date to Current Time in Hours/Mins/

Tags: php, variables, date, time

Say I have a date function that produces

**the output:** `2011-10-03`

**PHP:**

```
$todayDt = date('Y-m-d');
```

Anyway to get this date to instead show `2 days 1 hour ago`

Comment: date_diff http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php

Comment: You can use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/datetime.diff.php) and [DateInterval](php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php).

Comment: Would appreciate an example using my code

Comment: Just for clarification, how do you get 1 hour from the data you provided?  Neither the output from your function nor your example call to `date` to grab today's date provides enough precision to get a result that includes hours.

Comment: Php should be able to calculate this... from the current date and time on the server... right?

Comment: Yes, but for that calculation to actually have any meaning you have to provide it enough information, so if the output of your function was something like '2011-10-03 02:17:13' and your date call was `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`.  Otherwise, from what you've provided the closest you can get is days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function might be of some use. You might want to refine the check for months a bit, but this is just a quick example:

```
function RelativeTime($iTimestamp, $iLevel = 2)
{
    !ctype_digit($iTimestamp)
        && $iTimestamp = strtotime($iTimestamp);

    $iSecondsInADay = 86400;
    $aDisplay = array();

    // Start at the largest denominator
    $iDiff = time() - $iTimestamp;
    $aPeriods = array(
        array('Period'  => $iSecondsInADay * 356,   'Label'   => 'year'),
        array('Period'  => $iSecondsInADay * 31,    'Label'   => 'month'),
        array('Period'  => $iSecondsInADay,         'Label'   => 'day'),
        array('Period'  => 3600,                    'Label'   => 'hour'),
        array('Period'  => 60,                      'Label'   => 'minute'),
        array('Period'  => 1,                       'Label'   => 'second'),
    );

    foreach ($aPeriods as $aPeriod)
    {
        $iCount = floor($iDiff / $aPeriod['Period']);
        if ($iCount > 0)
        {
            $aDisplay[] = $iCount . ' ' . $aPeriod['Label'] . ($iCount > 1 ? 's' : '');
            $iDiff -= $iCount * $aPeriod['Period'];
        }
    }

    $iRange = count($aDisplay) > $iLevel
                ? $iLevel
                : count($aDisplay);
    return implode(' ', array_slice($aDisplay, 0, $iRange)) . ' ago';
}
```

And some examples of usage:

```
echo RelativeTime(time() - 102, 1);
// Will output: 1 minute ago

echo RelativeTime(time() - 2002);
// Will output: 33 minutes 22 seconds ago

echo RelativeTime(time() - 100002002, 6);
// Will output: 3 years 2 months 27 days 10 hours 20 minutes 2 seconds ago

echo RelativeTime('2011-09-05');
// Will output: 30 days 22 hours ago
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Can you explain what echo `RelativeTime(time() - 100002002, 6);` does

Comment: `RelativeTime(time() - 100002002, 6);` takes the timestamp specified (which is now - 100002002 seconds) and builds the label. The 6 specifies the level of detail required (6 levels of detail mean you get, starting from the largest date unit, 6 levels of detail: Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minutes, Seconds. If you'd specified only 2, you would only get Year, Month).

Comment: With a smaller time difference... like time() - 102 seconds you'll only get minutes and seconds. If you specify a level of detail of 1, then you'll only get the minutes.

Comment: Oh and finally, you can do this too:

`RelativeTime('2011-09-05');` which will give you `30 days 22 hours ago`

Comment: the problem with the above is, if it was anything less than a day away, it doesnt output the value. It gives you  2 ago   , not 2 hours for instance or 2 minutes...

Comment: Please provide an example of the function call you made. I can't recreate it.

Comment: Ah. made a small adjustment to the code. Should work properly now. Was trimming 1 part too many.

Answer (score 1):

This is post is just for a solution that does not use the `DateTime::diff` method.  It also uses inputs with greater precision, so be aware of that.

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$then = '2011-10-03 00:00:00';  // This will calculate the difference 
                                // between now and midnight October 3rd
$nowTime = strtotime($now);
$thenTime = strtotime($then);

$diff = $nowTime - $thenTime;

$secs = $diff % 60;
$diff = intval($diff / 60);
$minutes = $diff % 60;
$diff = intval($diff / 60);
$hours = $diff % 24;
$diff = intval($diff / 24);
$days = $diff;


echo($days . ' days ' . $hours . ' hours ' . $minutes . ' minutes ' . $secs . ' seconds ago');
```

At the moment I tested it, the output was:

> 2 days 16 hours 6 minutes 2 seconds ago

If all you want are the days and hours, then you can just choose to echo those two out:

```
echo($days . ' days ' . $hours . ' hours ago');
```

> 2 days 16 hours ago